# Selection for Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq

How can I select the List of ExtrasName and ExtrasId in the following query.
The query contains some mathematical operations aswell.

```
var query = 
                    from a in _context.Cities
                    from b in a.CityExtras
                    where a.CityId == CityId && extraIds.Contains(b.ExtrasId)
                    group new { a, b } by new { a.PricePerSqM , a.Name, a.CityId , } into g 
                    select new 
                    {
                        City = g.Key.Name,
                        PricePerSqM = g.Key.PricePerSqM,
                        TotalPrice = g.Sum(x => x.b.Price) + g.Key.PricePerSqM * squareMeter
                    };
```

My Models are:

```
 public class Extras
    {
        public int ExtrasId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string ExtrasName { get; set; }
        public ICollection<CityExtras> CityExtras { get; set; }
    }

public class City
    {
        public int CityId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int PricePerSqM { get; set; }
        public ICollection<CityExtras> CityExtras { get; set; }
    }

 public class CityExtras
    {

        public int CityId { get; set; }
        public City City { get; set; }
        public Extras Extras { get; set; }
        public int ExtrasId { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }

    }
```

I need ExtrasNames and ExtrasId in the query

Comment: They *are* filtered by CityId because they belong to the city that's filtered by `a.CityId == CityId`.

Comment: yes they are already filtered.. my problem is to include ExtrasName and ExtrasId.

Comment: Did you try add this in you select `ExtrasList = g.Select(x => x.b.Extras).ToList()`?

Answer (score 0):

As they stand, your models are not going to allow you to do this easily. You should add navigation properties to your models, then your Linq will be much cleaner (no need for the double `select`), and you will be able to navigate upwards to the `Extra` object and get the data you want.

Comment: I am new to this, unable to understand, can u please guide in detail. what changes i should make in models?